# How to setup the Next Button to not be available until User Selects at least one Check Box?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Hello Im using bootstrap carousel to create this question / sign up form using bootstrap carousel for the animation. How can I set it up to where the next button is not available until the user at least selects one check box?

When  comes to javascript I barely know the syntax so any help I would really appreciate it.
Javascript is still super confusing to me. Just FYI after the user clicks on the "next" button the carousel animation will slide to the next section / page.

HTML

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="medical-question-btns btn-group btn-group-toggle btn-group-vertical"
        data-toggle="buttons">


        <!-- ============= LABEL ============= -->


        <label class="btn btn-primary my-2 pl-5" id="label_q18_a1">

            <svg class="check-box-outline-blank icon-left icon-circle"
                id="label_q18_a1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                width="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path
                    d="M19 5v14H5V5h14m0-2H5c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2z" />
            </svg>

            <svg class="check-box-checked icon-left icon-check-circle"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="bi bi-check-circle-fill">
                <path
                    d="M19 3H5c-1.11 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.11 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.89-2-2-2zm-9 14l-5-5 1.41-1.41L10 14.17l7.59-7.59L19 8l-9 9z" />
            </svg>

            <input type="checkbox" name="q18_a1" id="q18_a1"
                autocomplete="off">
            <p>Any condition where sex is not advised</p>
        </label>

        

        <label class="btn btn-primary my-2 pl-5" id="label_q18_a2">
            <svg class="check-box-outline-blank icon-left icon-circle"
                id="label_q18_a1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                width="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path
                    d="M19 5v14H5V5h14m0-2H5c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2z" />
            </svg>

            <svg class="check-box-checked icon-left icon-check-circle"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="bi bi-check-circle-fill">
                <path
                    d="M19 3H5c-1.11 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.11 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.89-2-2-2zm-9 14l-5-5 1.41-1.41L10 14.17l7.59-7.59L19 8l-9 9z" />
            </svg>
            <input type="checkbox" name="q18_a2" id="q18_a2"
                autocomplete="off">
            <p>Kidney problems including having had a kidney transplant</p>
        </label>

        <label class="btn btn-primary my-2 pl-5" id="label_q18_a3">
            <svg class="check-box-outline-blank icon-left icon-circle"
                id="label_q18_a1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                width="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path
                    d="M19 5v14H5V5h14m0-2H5c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2z" />
            </svg>

            <svg class="check-box-checked icon-left icon-check-circle"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="bi bi-check-circle-fill">
                <path
                    d="M19 3H5c-1.11 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.11 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.89-2-2-2zm-9 14l-5-5 1.41-1.41L10 14.17l7.59-7.59L19 8l-9 9z" />
            </svg>
            <input type="checkbox" name="q18_a3" id="q18_a3"
                autocomplete="off">
            <p>Liver problems</p>
        </label>

        <label class="btn btn-primary my-2 pl-5" id="label_q18_a4">
            <svg class="check-box-outline-blank icon-left icon-circle"
                id="label_q18_a1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                width="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path
                    d="M19 5v14H5V5h14m0-2H5c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2z" />
            </svg>

            <svg class="check-box-checked icon-left icon-check-circle"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="bi bi-check-circle-fill">
                <path
                    d="M19 3H5c-1.11 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.11 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.89-2-2-2zm-9 14l-5-5 1.41-1.41L10 14.17l7.59-7.59L19 8l-9 9z" />
            </svg>
            <input type="checkbox" name="q18_a4" id="q18_a4"
                autocomplete="off">
            <p>Neurological problems like multiple sclerosis or motor neuron
                disease</p>
        </label>

        <label class="btn btn-primary my-2 pl-5" id="label_q18_a5">
            <svg class="check-box-outline-blank icon-left icon-circle"
                id="label_q18_a1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                width="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path
                    d="M19 5v14H5V5h14m0-2H5c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2z" />
            </svg>

            <svg class="check-box-checked icon-left icon-check-circle"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="bi bi-check-circle-fill">
                <path
                    d="M19 3H5c-1.11 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.11 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.89-2-2-2zm-9 14l-5-5 1.41-1.41L10 14.17l7.59-7.59L19 8l-9 9z" />
            </svg>
            <input type="checkbox" name="q18_a5" id="q18_a5"
                autocomplete="off">
            <p>HIV</p>
        </label>

        <label class="btn btn-primary my-2 pl-5" id="label_q18_a6">
            <svg class="check-box-outline-blank icon-left icon-circle"
                id="label_q18_a1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                width="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path
                    d="M19 5v14H5V5h14m0-2H5c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2z" />
            </svg>

            <svg class="check-box-checked icon-left icon-check-circle"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="bi bi-check-circle-fill">
                <path
                    d="M19 3H5c-1.11 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.11 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.89-2-2-2zm-9 14l-5-5 1.41-1.41L10 14.17l7.59-7.59L19 8l-9 9z" />
            </svg>
            <input type="checkbox" name="q18_a6" id="q18_a6"
                autocomplete="off">
            <p>Spinal injury or paralysis</p>
        </label>

        <label class="btn btn-primary my-2 pl-5" id="label_q18_a7">
            <svg class="check-box-outline-blank icon-left icon-circle"
                id="label_q18_a1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                width="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path
                    d="M19 5v14H5V5h14m0-2H5c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2z" />
            </svg>

            <svg class="check-box-checked icon-left icon-check-circle"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="bi bi-check-circle-fill">
                <path
                    d="M19 3H5c-1.11 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.11 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.89-2-2-2zm-9 14l-5-5 1.41-1.41L10 14.17l7.59-7.59L19 8l-9 9z" />
            </svg>
            <input type="checkbox" name="q18_a7" id="q18_a7"
                autocomplete="off">
            <p>Previous surgery on your prostate or pelvis</p>
        </label>

        <label class="btn btn-primary my-2 pl-5" id="label_q18_a8">
            <svg class="check-box-outline-blank icon-left icon-circle"
                id="label_q18_a1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                width="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path
                    d="M19 5v14H5V5h14m0-2H5c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2z" />
            </svg>

            <svg class="check-box-checked icon-left icon-check-circle"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="bi bi-check-circle-fill">
                <path
                    d="M19 3H5c-1.11 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.11 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.89-2-2-2zm-9 14l-5-5 1.41-1.41L10 14.17l7.59-7.59L19 8l-9 9z" />
            </svg>
            <input type="checkbox" name="q18_a8" id="q18_a8"
                autocomplete="off">
            <p>Radiation therapy to your pelvis</p>
        </label>

        <label class="btn btn-primary my-2 pl-5" id="label_q18_a9">
            <svg class="check-box-outline-blank icon-left icon-circle"
                id="label_q18_a1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                width="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path
                    d="M19 5v14H5V5h14m0-2H5c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2z" />
            </svg>

            <svg class="check-box-checked icon-left icon-check-circle"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="bi bi-check-circle-fill">
                <path
                    d="M19 3H5c-1.11 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.11 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.89-2-2-2zm-9 14l-5-5 1.41-1.41L10 14.17l7.59-7.59L19 8l-9 9z" />
            </svg>
            <input type="checkbox" name="q18_a9" id="q18_a9"
                autocomplete="off">
            <p>None apply</p>
        </label>

        <!-- ============= LABEL ============= -->
    </div>
</div>
```

BUTTON HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-row col">
        <div class="col mt-3 text-right">
            <a href="#medical-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <label class="btn my-4 btn-lg btn-lightgray btnNavigate"
                    id="med_questions_back">
                    <svg class="icon-dark" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                        fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                            d="M11.354 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708L5.707 8l5.647 5.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z">
                        </path>
                    </svg>
                    Back
                </label>
            </a>
        </div>

        <!-- NEXT BUTTON -->

        <div class="col mt-3 text-left">
            <!-- SLIDE NEXT BUTTON -->
            <label class="btn my-4 btn-lg btn-green btnNavigate" id="med_questions_next"
                data-target="#medical-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                Next
                <svg class="icon-dark" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                    class="bi bi-chevron-right" fill="currentColor"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                        d="M4.646 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.293 8 4.646 2.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z" />
                </svg>
            </label>
            <!-- SLIDE NEXT BUTTON -->


        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple task for JS like below. You can use an onlick event on the checkbox to run the script. the script then checks all checkboxes declared if they checked or not. if a single one is checked, it will display the button.

```js
function nextButton() {
  var one = document.getElementById("one"),
      two = document.getElementById("two"),
      three = document.getElementById("three"),
      next = document.getElementById("next");
  if (one.checked == false &&
     two.checked == false &&
     three.checked == false) {
       next.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    next.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#next {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="one" id="one" onclick="nextButton()" autocomplete="off">Checkbox #1
</label>
<br>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="two" id="two" onclick="nextButton()" autocomplete="off">Checkbox #2
</label>
<br>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="three" id="three" onclick="nextButton()" autocomplete="off">Checkbox #3
</label>
<br><br>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this out tonight? Just curious how did you know how to write this? Did you google this or you wrote it from scratch?

Comment: I wrote it from scratch. This is a very simple thing. Not the most effient solution if you have something like 20 ceckboxes, but the easiest solution to understand imo.